# Is there a good way to make a preview image for a web page?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to make a portfolio of my work that has preview images for each project. I know that I could do this by manually taking screenshots of each page, but I'd like something more dynamic. I've considered using an iframe for each page, but that seems like it would be inefficient and silly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manual screenshots will yield the best performance and the most control over how you want to display sites on your portfolio.

Iframes will yield the absolute worst possible performance of your site as you will literally be loading every site on a single page.

I have seen other solutions out there where you can dynamically pass in a URL of a site to generate screenshots.

Here is a PHP based example from a service called https://www.url2png.com/

`<?php
      // it really is this simple
      $apikey="YOUR_API_KEY";
      $secret="YOUR_SECRET_KEY";
      $token=md5("url=target.com" . $secret);
      $img="api.url2png.com/v6/$apikey/$token/png/?url=target.com";
  ?>
<img src='http://<?php echo $img; ?>' />`

Which generates the following image tag:

`<img src='https://api.url2png.com/v6/P4DE5D1C99D8EF/6642cb9065894d17b959364ddb0cec6e/png/?url=target.com' />`

It is my "personal" opinion that a good portfolio will contain screenshots of a mobile, tablet, and desktop version of the site which makes the manual process the only "great" choice.

Comment: +1 for the service. You should offload this kind of work to someone else if you can. This API seems fairly nice!